# How to make Kotlin Fuel json serializer to compile?

Tags: kotlin, fuel

I'm trying to use [Fuel JSON deserializer](https://github.com/kittinunf/fuel/blob/master/fuel-json/README.md) so I added it to my dependencies like this:

```
implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel:2.2.1'
implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-json:2.2.1'
```

However each time I'm running `./gradlew clean build` I'm getting this error:

```
> Task :compileKotlin FAILED
e: /DirToMyClass/MyClass.kt: (55, 26): Cannot access class 'org.json.JSONObject'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

I've run `./gradlew dependencies` to check that there are no other dependency importing `org.json` and the only one is `fuel-json`.

```
+--- com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-json:2.2.1
|    +--- com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel:2.2.1 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.50 -> 1.3.60 (*)
|    \--- org.json:json:20180813
```

What can I be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed this by changing the dependencies to:

```
implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel:2.2.1'
implementation('com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-json:2.2.1') {
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}

implementation 'org.json:json:20190722'
```

Using a newer version of `org.json:json`.